# How to post to a WordPress contact form plugin (Custom Contact Forms) from a Vue/Nuxt app

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, wordpress-rest-api

- I have built my first VueJS/Nuxt app that pulls content from the
  WordPress REST API, the content is all being pulled in nicely and I
  would now like to allow visitors to complete a contact form on the
  app (website) which will post the data to a WordPress Plugin (Custom
  Contact Forms).
- I have exposed the API endpoints, etc. I've created the form in
  WordPress and added it to the page as shortcode.
- The form loads, and once you click submit the page refreshes with a
  query string added to the URL, but no success message and when I
  check WordPress there are no submissions.

**It seems this is not the way to do it.**

> If I was to instead create a Vue Component with the form in it, with
>   the IDs on the inputs set to match the form in WordPress, how would I
>   then get it to submit the data and make use of the plugin to send
>   notifications?
>
> I can't find anything here on by searching Google on how to make this
>   work - can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: I've installed the plugin and took a look and the form is submitted via an AJAX POST request. The form data ultimately ends up in the tables wp_posts and wp_postmeta. I'm guessing you'll have an easier time if you analyze the database rows that get added and replicate them.

Comment: @ChrisG So basically, send a submision through WordPress itself and then look at the JSON output in Postman to see where to post the submission to and use Ajax to submit the form?

Comment: You can try to replicate the client-side JS code, yes. Or just implement your own POST endpoint and simply add the form data to the database using ccf's format, so it'll appear in the dashboard. (also, just to make sure this isn't an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/): do you really need the Wordpress plugin in the first place? what is the main goal here?)

Comment: @ChrisG Well, that's crux of my question, really. It's my understanding that I need the plugin to be able to view the submissions in the WordPress admin. So I'd essentially be using the plugin as a framework to create my own form and submit the data using its structure. Does that make sense? And is that even possible? Love that link by the way! I've been in that situation many times!

Comment: I guess it's possible somehow, but I don't think it's the best solution. Adding a basic submission table to the admin interface (or to a password protected website page) is probably easier than the CCF route.

Comment: @ChrisG I have no idea how to create a submission table to add to the admin interface - would that involve writing custom functions in WordPress?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186102/discussion-between-alxthered-and-chris-g).